# Wordpress/Woocommerce Plugin code not showing up

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to add some custom meta boxes to the Woocommerce Product Page. When I add this code to the wc-meta-boxes-functions.php file it works but when I add it into my Plugin file it does nothing. What am I doing wrong?

```
namespace Inc\Base;
use Inc\Base\BaseController;
/**
* 
*/
class WoocommerceController extends BaseController
{

    function register(){
    add_action('woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'woocommerce_product_custom_fields');
// Save Fields
add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woocommerce_product_custom_fields_save');
}

// Display Fields

function woocommerce_product_custom_fields()
    {
    global $woocommerce, $post;
    echo '<div class="product_custom_field">';
    // Custom Product Text Field
    woocommerce_wp_text_input(
        array(
            'id' => '_custom_product_text_field',
            'placeholder' => 'Custom Product Text Field',
            'label' => __('Custom Product Text Field', 'woocommerce'),
            'desc_tip' => 'true'
        )
    );
    //Custom Product Number Field
    woocommerce_wp_text_input(
        array(
            'id' => '_custom_product_number_field',
            'placeholder' => 'Custom Product Number Field',
            'label' => __('Custom Product Number Field', 'woocommerce'),
            'type' => 'number',
            'custom_attributes' => array(
                'step' => 'any',
                'min' => '0'
            )
        )
    );
    //Custom Product  Textarea
    woocommerce_wp_textarea_input(
        array(
            'id' => '_custom_product_textarea',
            'placeholder' => 'Custom Product Textarea',
            'label' => __('Custom Product Textarea', 'woocommerce')
        )
    );
    echo '</div>';
}

}
```

Comment: that must work as a plugin. are you sure the plugin is activated ?

Comment: @Kaperto yes pretty sure because the other functions do work

Comment: Are you run new WoocommerceController() ?

Comment: @Dmitry Where can I do that, can I do it in the same file?

Answer (score 0):

so I found the answer:
you have to write `add_action('woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', array($this, 'woocommerce_product_custom_fields') );`
Thank you for the answers!